# How to convert solution in to basic formula?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to convert my problem in to basic formula so that I can use it for much bigger problem but I can't able to think. My main problem is to use this same strategy for large number of sequence

Here 1,2,3 are objects which are connected together. 
For example if I got output as sequence (from permutation):-
2-1-3 ; 2-3-1
Now I have to compare these two sequence on the basis of distance of its center of mass.

for 2-1-3, First I  calculated the center of mass of 2 and 1 both together and then measured its distance from center of mass of 2 (d21), after that I calculated the center of mass of all objects (1,2,3) and its distance from center of mass of 2 and 1 both together (d213); and at last dx1= d21+d213

similary, I did for sequence 2-3-1 and calculated dx2 = d23+ d231

In other words, I want dx1, dx2 values as output, I coded the program for that as shown,

```
m1=input('the value of m1 is')
m2=input('the value of m2 is')
m3=input('the value of m3 is')
x1=input('the value of x1 is')
x2=input('the value of x2 is')
y1=input('the value of y1 is')
y2=input('the value of y2 is')
y3=input('the value of y3 is')
x3=input('the value of x3 is')
% here m is the mass and x and y are the center of mass of an respective object
% X11 and Y11 are the center of mass of all three objects connected together
Y11=input('the value of Y11 is')
X11=input('the value of X11 is')
[X21,Y21]= Centerofmass(m1,m2,x1,x2,y1,y2)
[X213,Y213]= Centerofmassy(m1,m2,m3,x3,X21,Y21,y3)
[X23,Y23]= Centerofmassyy(m3,m2,x3,x2,y3,y2)
[X231,Y231]= Centerofmassyyy(m1,m2,m3,x1,X23,Y23,y1)
X = [x2,y2;X21,Y21];
d21 = pdist(X,'euclidean');
X = [X21,Y21;X213,Y213];
d213 = pdist(X,'euclidean');
dx1=d21+d213

X = [x2,y2;X23,Y23];
d23 = pdist(X,'euclidean');
X = [X23,Y23;X231,Y231];
d231 = pdist(X,'euclidean');
dx2=d23+d231

% Where functions are

% X21 and Y21 are the center of mass of 2 and 1 connected together
function[X21,Y21]= Centerofmass(m1,m2,x1,x2,y1,y2)
X21=((m1*x1)+(m2*x2))/(m1+m2);
Y21=((m1*y1)+(m2*y2))/(m1+m2);
end

% X213 and Y213 are the center of mass of all objects connected together
function [X213,Y213]= Centerofmassy(m1,m2,m3,x3,X21,Y21,y3)
X213=(((m1+m2)*X21)+(m3*x3))/(m1+m2+m3);
Y213=(((m1+m2)*Y21)+(m3*y3))/(m1+m2+m3); 
end

% X23 and Y23 are the center of mass of 2 and 3 connected together
function[X23,Y23]= Centerofmassyy(m3,m2,x3,x2,y3,y2)
X23=((m3*x3)+(m2*x2))/(m3+m2);
Y23=((m3*y3)+(m2*y2))/(m3+m2);
end

% X231 and Y231 are the center of mass of all three objects connected together
function [X231,Y231]= Centerofmassyyy(m1,m2,m3,x1,X23,Y23,y1)
X231=(((m3+m2)*X23)+(m1*x1))/(m1+m2+m3);
Y231=(((m3+m2)*Y23)+(m1*y1))/(m1+m2+m3); 
end
```

How can I use the same strategy for bigger problems,  I mean the problem having more than 7 objects and more then 60 outputs or sequences to calculate distance????

Comment: One way to go about it would be to let the user specify how many objects there are first. Once you have that information, store all the information into a single N x M, where N = object# and M = [m, x, y] and use loops to iterate through the length of the dimensions to accumulate your answers.

Comment: @Elijah Rockers thank you  oops I didn't know too much about Matlab, Infact this is my first matlab code, if you can tell me exactly for the given problem with three objects , then it will really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following code ought to get you headed in the right direction. This will create an array called `data` Where the rows represent objects, and the columns (1, 2, and 3) represent m, x, and y respectively. This will allow you to have a variable number of objects, with different masses and X,Y locations.

```
objects = input('How many objects: ');

data = zeros(objects,3);

for k = 1:objects
    % INPUT OBJECT VALUES
    data(k,1) = input(strcat('Enter mass of object #',int2str(k),': '));
    data(k,2) = input(strcat('Enter X-value of object #',int2str(k),': '));
    data(k,3) = input(strcat('Enter Y-value of object #',int2str(k),': '));
end
```

The second part of the code is going to involve a little bit of simple combinatorics. You will need another similar `for` loop that will iterate through each of the possible combinations (which will depend on how many objects there are) and calculate (and store in another variable) the resulting center of mass calculations.

In particular, you will be using a concept called 'combinations'.

```
for k = 1:objects
     combinations = combnk(1:objects,k)
     for c = size(combinations,1)
         % combinations(c,:) here will be the indices of each
         % possible combination. This is where you will calculate
         % the center of mass
     end
end
```

Each row of `combinations` in the above `for` loop will be all possible combinations of your objects. You'll then want another `for` loop inside of that one to loop through each combinations and calculate the result. I'll leave that part up to you.